# Django: aggregate if all boolean model fields is True

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.model):
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I can detemine if all cars were sold by making two queries:

```
sold_count = Car.objects.filter(sold=True).count()
all_count = Car.objects.count()

are_all_sold = (all_count - sold_count) == 0
```

Since this operation is very frequent on my app, I am wondering if it is possible to do it in just one DB query? e.g. using [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/) or [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/), etc.

just an update, I can get the stats on how many were sold & unsold by one single query:

```
Car.objects.values("sold").annotate(count=Count("sold"))
<QuerySet [{'sold': False, 'count': 1}, {'sold': True, 'count': 9}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do that by using Model Manager.

in model.py:

```
from django.db import models

class CarManager(models.Manager):
    def are_all_sold_or_not(self):    
        sold_count = Car.objects.filter(sold=True).count()
        all_count = Car.objects.count()
        return all_count == sold_count

class Car(models.model):
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    objects = CarManager()
```

in views.py

```
def myview(request):
  .....
  .
  are_all_sold = Car.objects.are_all_sold_or_not()
  .
  .
```

You can read more about Model Manager in the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/

Comment: it doesn't change the fact the database is being queried twice.

Comment: You can not query the database once because here you are querying for two different things which are 'all objects' and 'objects with sold=True', so you can not query the database once. But you can reduce the code to be like this:
```
return Car.objects.count() == Car.objects.filter(sold=True).count()

```